# Blood Pressure problem given equation

Tags: trigonometry

The  blood  pressure  (P)  of  an  individual  after t seconds  with  a  heart  rate  of  70 beats/min. can be modeled by the function,

P(t) = 100 + 20 sin(7π/3)t

In  the  time  interval  from  0s  to  1s,  determine  the  times  at  which  the  blood pressure is 100 mmHg.

I understand what the question is asking me, but I don't know how to solve this problem on mathematica. I'm new to the program so bear with me.

Comment: Please change your title to one that actually refers to the question... not some generic one meaning nothing more than "I need help."

Comment: Off Topic (not to be taken too seriously): Is the blood pressure really such a nice harmonic oscillation? Another remark: the time period should be 6/7 instead of 1; otherwise you get hard pressure change (jump) on continuing periodically to greater t.

Comment: Seems like a question to take to a TA or instructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Solve[100 + 20 Sin[7 Pi/3 t] == 100 && 0 <= t <= 1, t]
```

> {{t -> 0}, {t -> 3/7}, {t -> 6/7}}

here is the plot

```
Plot[100 + 20 Sin[7 Pi/3 t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]